# Does the parallel regression assumption hold if the Omnibus is non-significant but some covariates are?

Tags: r, ordered-logit

I have created an adjusted ordinal logistic regression fit:

```
adjfit <- MASS::polr(outcome ~ hxcopd + sex + race + age + diabetes + smoke + dyspnea + fnstatus2 + ascites + hxchf + hypermed + renafail + dialysis + steroid + bleeddis + wtloss + lap, data = df)

adjfit.step <- MASS::stepAIC(adjfit, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)
```

In order to test the **parallel regression assumption**, I conduct a Brant test with the `brant` package:

```
> brant::brant(adjfit.step)
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Test for                          X2    df  probability 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Omnibus                         -719.04 36  1
hxcopdTRUE                      0.44    4   0.98
age                             6.26    4   0.18
diabetesTRUE                    1.7     4   0.79
fnstatus2Partially dependent    15.57   4   0
ascitesTRUE                     127.39  4   0
hxchfTRUE                       1.52    4   0.82
dialysisTRUE                    19.23   4   0
bleeddisTRUE                    2.21    4   0.7
wtlossTRUE                      39.57   4   0
------------------------------------------------------------ 

H0: Parallel Regression Assumption holds

Warning message:
In brant::brant(adjfit.step) :
  1402 combinations in table(dv,ivs) do not occur. Because of that, the test results might be invalid.
```

**1) How do I interpret the case where the Omnibus is non-significant (1) but there are various covariates with < 0.05? Does the parallel regression assumption hold?**

**2) How can I either address the warning message or further assess if the lack of 1402 combinations makes my test results invalid?**

Comment: There’s a lot going on in here, Dylan. Many people on this forum will dissuade you from using stepwise regression, which is what you seem to be doing. This method of variable selection is known to suffer from bias. You would be better off to use a model informed by clinical insights rather than one produced by stepwise variable selection.

Comment: In general, if the proportional odds assumption is violated by one or more predictor variables, you would need to relax the proportional odds assumption for the variable(s) in question.  If the overall Brant test is at odds with the predictor-specific ones, you can perhaps supplement it with a likelihood ratio test?

Comment: In general, omnibus tests can lead you astray so if anything, I would trust the predictor-specific tests in this case. They are also not very informative - if they produce a significant p-value, that means the data provide evidence that the proportional odds assumption is violated for at least one predictor variable. But they tell you nothing about which predictor variable(s) may be responsible for that violation so that you know where to relax the proportionality assumption.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the brant package to comment on the warning - you could try Googling the warning in question (minus the specifics related to your data set) to see if anything helpful pops up. Perhaps others here might be able to help you with this specific issue.