# Interpreting ordinal regression output in R polr()

Tags: r, model, ordinal-data, ordered-logit, polr

I ran an ordinal regression in R using polr(), and have checked the proportional odds assumptions with brant() from the brant package. I am very new to ordinal regression and I am a bit confused about how to interpret the output of the polr model.

My dependent variable is an ordered factor with 11 levels, and I have a series of independent variables, some continuous and some discrete.

Could anyone refer me to a relatively easy to understand guide to interpreting the outputs of polr() (coefficients, fit, etc)?

I have been following [this guide](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/ologit-coefficients/), as suggested in the answer to a similar question. I have obtained the p values, CIs, and odds ratios. However, I am a bit confused about how to interpret them, as, unlike the example linked above, my DV has more than two levels.

The answer to [this question on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490913/interpreting-coefficients-from-ordinal-regression-r-polr-function) was also quite useful, but the independent variable in the example is binary and I was wondering how the interpretation would translate with, say, a continuous variable.

In short, how would I translate statements such as: "For every one unit increase in student’s GPA the odds of being more likely to apply (very or somewhat likely versus unlikely) is multiplied 1.85 times (i.e., increases 85%), holding constant all other variables" (from the 1st example above), but **with a dependent variable with many levels?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to think about this model using the latent-variable representation.

For simplicity, let's assume that your model has only one independent variable (GPA), and that the dependent variable is ordinal with 5 categories (instead of 11).

Suppose that every student has a score, $Z_i$, that is on a continuous scale. The model equation is
$$
Z_i = \underbrace{\beta x_i}_{\eta_i} + \epsilon_i
$$
where $x_i$ is the student's GPA, and $\epsilon_i \sim \mathrm{Logistic}(0,1)$. We thus have $Z_i \sim \mathrm{Logistic}(\eta_i,1)$, where the linear predictor $\eta_i$ is the location. Here are the density functions for the scores of two students, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$:

[image]

You don't get to observe the value of $Z_i$ directly (it's a latent variable). Instead, imagine that you have cutpoints $\zeta_1<\zeta_2<\zeta_3<\zeta_4$ along the horizontal axis, and you only know which group $Z_i$ falls into.

[image]

This is your independent variable, $Y_i$. Specifically, you observe:
$$
Y_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } Z_i<\zeta_1 \\ 
2 & \text{if }\zeta_1<Z_i<\zeta_2 \\
3 & \text{if }\zeta_2<Z_i<\zeta_3 \\
4 & \text{if }\zeta_3<Z_i<\zeta_4 \\
5 & \text{if }\zeta_4 < Z_i \end{cases}
$$
The plots below show that $P(Y_1=2)>P(Y_2=2)$, as $Z_1$ is likelier than $Z_2$ to fall between these two cutpoints.
[image]
[image]
Notice that some cutpoints are closer together, so those categories will not be observed as often.

We have:
\begin{align*}
P(Y=2) &= P(\zeta_1<Z<\zeta_2) \\
& = P(\zeta_1<\eta + \epsilon_i<\zeta_2) \\
& = P(\zeta_1 - \eta< \epsilon_i<\zeta_2- \eta)  \\
& = \sigma(\zeta_2- \eta) - \sigma(\zeta_1 - \eta)
\end{align*}
where $\sigma$ is the CDF of the $\mathrm{Logistic}(0,1)$ distribution, i.e. the inverse of the logit function.

Notice that we have
$$
P(Y>k)=\sigma(\eta-\zeta_k) \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{logit}(P(Y>k))=\eta - \zeta_k\,.
$$
A one-unit increase in GPA changes the linear predictor from $\eta$ to $\eta+\beta$, so the log-odds of a student falling in a category higher than $k$ (for any $k$) increase by $\beta$.

It's also helpful to interpret the parameters by comparing individual cases, e.g., the probability of each value of $Y$ for a student who is average in every predictor, versus one who the same but with a GPA that is one point higher.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the visualisation actually helped a lot. I was more concerned about interpreting R's outputs and coefficient tables tho, do you have any tips for that?

Comment: Good point! I've updated the answer.